# How can I track which (or how many) emails have been opened by the recipient?

Tags: php, email

I'm working on making our email sending tool better and more complete by adding reports on how many of the sent emails have been successfully sent, recieved, opened, etc. for a client with special requests. I've looked around and couldnt find any reliable way to tell if a recipient opened the email as it seems like Read Receipt requests are usually ignored by most email clients.

Is there any way to do it reliably or am I stuck with the unreliable read receipt request method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a simple image (HTML Mails Only)  in the mail ...

Something like this

```
<img src="http://domain.com/tracker.php?emailHash=xxx&emailID=99" width=1 height=1>
```

`tracker.php` would contain a simple script that can keep track of the user information

For more Information See

[Track Email Open](http://www.voicent.com/email-marketing/track-email-open.php)

[How to make a simple tracking image with PHP](http://thatsmith.com/2008/11/how-to-make-tracking-images-with-php)

Comment: This is a web-bug, i don't think this should be recommended.

Comment: A [web-bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug) is a technique used by spammers, to get valuable email-adresses (confirmed that they are in use).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. As for the spam issue, the use of the email sender is controlled entirely by our app with limits on emails per hour and the entities the emails are sent to (you can't just enter a bunch of emails), it will be used exclusively to send newsletters and forms to current customers.

Comment: @martinstoekli So you are saying companies like Constant Contact and Mail Chimp are doing something they shouldn't by using these techniques?

Comment: @Pitchinnate - The technique is neither reliable (email clients won't load this images without confirmation), nor will a user be happy if he is tracked, is he?

Comment: @martinstoekli - I'm not saying it is reliable but given the current technology it is the only technique available. I don't think most users care, if they do then they will simply not allow images. If a lot of users really did care and got mad about it then constant contact and huge companies like it would be out of business because everyone would unsubscribe from any mailing list that came from them.

Comment: @Pitchinnate - Users are well protected by their email clients, some years ago this was a serious problem because of the spam (mail preview confirms address). The same applies to mail servers, they do not send error codes, because this would confirm existing adresses. I don't see it as a serious problem today, but i wonder what such companies gain. My email-provider has a verification system which asks the user to click a link to see the mail, this is well explained and not behind my back (though it's not **the** solution...).

Comment: @martinstoeckli It's pretty useful for a company to see how effective their campaign/newsletter is. It's much easier to see how a campaign target responds to the campaign and why if you know wether he was interested enough to actually open the email. If the recipient doesn't display images (especially true for the picture format emails that are abundant now) you simply tag him as 'unopened' since he didn't actually read the email.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks God there is no reliable way to do this. You could use the "Track Email Open" link suggested by Baba but every modern E-Mail Client will not load remote Images until the user Allows it.

It's good that this isn't possible, imagine Spammers could know if you opened their mail or not...